# Best way to replace values in a list based on many indexes

Tags: python

I have list like this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

idx = [2,5,7]
```

I want to replace values in l with 0, using indexes from idx. For now I do:

```
for i in idx:
    l[i] = 0
```

This give: l = [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 7, 0, 9, 10]

Is there better, faster, more pythonic way. This is only small example, but what if I have huge lists?

Comment: That is pretty much the fastest, most pythonic way. Come on, have a little confidence in your code.

Comment: you should look at the time-complexity of operations on a list, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: In numpy this is just `l[idx] = 0`. You should check out numpy. Also "l" is a terrible variable name, don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is perfectly fine. You could write a list comprehension, like this:

```
[v if i not in idx else 0 for i, v in enumerate(l)]
```

Or change it in place by iterating over `l`

```
for i, v in enumerate(l):
    if i in idx:
        l[i] = 0
```

But I find that harder to read, and very likely slower. I don't think any other solution will beat yours by a significant margin, ignoring CPU caching.

Comment: Depends on the CPU. If `idx` contains most indexes, and is in random order, it'll be writing all over the place in the memory. But yes, for smaller `idx` it will very likely be slower.

Comment: It is six times slower. It makes no sense to iterate over all the list as opposed to accessing by index

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about huge lists, you should really try not to create a new list, as the new list will require space in memory in addition to your input lists.

Now, let's consider the indices that you want to set to `0`. These indices are contained in a list (`idx`), which itself could be just as long as the list with numbers (`l`). So, if you were to do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    if i in idx:
        l[i] = 0
```

it would take O(mn) time, where m is the number of elements in `idx` and n is the number of elements in `l`. This is a really slow algorithm.

Now, you really can't do much faster than O(m), seeing as you have to consider every element in `idx`. But since m is strictly bounded from above by n, it's definitely a better strategy to loop over `idx` instead:

```
for i in idx:
    l[i] = 0
```

But let's consider that `idx` might contain elements that are not valid indices of `l` (i.e. there is at least one element in `idx` whose value is greater than the largest index in `l`). Then, you could do this:

```
for i in idx:
    if i<len(l):
        l[i] = 0
```

or:

```
for ind in (i for i in idx if i<len(L)):
    l[ind] = 0
```

Now, this makes O(m) comparisons, which could potentially be improved upon. For example, if `idx` were sorted, then a modified binary search could provide the appropriate slice of `idx` that has valid indices:

```
def binSearch(L, idx, i=0, j=None):  # note that the list is not sliced, unlike some common binary search implementations. This saves on additional space
    if not idx:
        return pad
    if j==None:
        j = len(idx)-1
    mid = (i+j)//2
    if idx[mid] == len(L)-1:
        return mid
    elif idx[mid] > len(L)-1:
        return binSearch(L, idx, i, mid-1)
    else:
        return binSearch(L, idx, mid+1, j)
```

So now, you could replace only the valid indices without any comparisons at all:

```
for ind in range(binSearch(L, idx)):
    l[idx[ind]] = 0
```

Note that this approach takes O(log m) time to apply `binSearch` on `idx` in the first place

This would work if `idx` were already sorted. However, if that is an invalid assumption, then you might want to sort it yourself, which would cost O(m log m) time, which would be slower than the aforementioned O(m) implementation.

---

Yet, if `idx` were sufficiently large, you could try a distributed approach, with [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def replace(l, idx):
    numWorkers = mp.cpu_count()*2 -1
    qIn = mp.Queue(maxsize=len(idx))
    qOut = mp.Queue()
    procs = [mp.Process(target=slave, args=(L, qIn, qOut)) for _ in range(numWorkers)]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    for i in idx:
        qIn.put(i)

    numFinished = 0
    while numFinished != numWorkers:
        i = qOut.get()
        if i is None:
            numFinished += 1
            continue
        l[i] = 0


def slave(L, qIn, qOut):
    for i in iter(qIn.get, None):
        if i< len(L):
            qOut.put(i)
    qOut.put(None)
```

Of course, you could further improve this by adding the `binSearch` to the distributed solution as well, but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 1):

Don't create another list for index. Instead:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
index = 1
while index < len(l):
    if index == 2:
        l[index] = 0
    elif index == 5:
        l[index] = 0
    elif index == 7:
        l[index] = 0
    index += 1
print(l)
```

You do not have to use "elif" statements if you combine them all on one line with an "or" statement. For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
index = 1
while index < len(l):
    if (index == 2) or (index == 5) or (index == 7):        
        l[index] = 0
    index += 1
print(l)
```

Comment: Would be better to put those indices into a data structure, to let the code scale up. Imagine if there were a million of these indices, writing that many conditionals (in separate el/if statements or conditionals of just one) would be very painful. Maintaining them in a set/list/tuple would be easier